# What is a efficient way to condense a List of objects to based on an object value?

Tags: java, javascript, list, arraylist, collections

I have an ArrayList of Objects. The object has five fields: id, date, name, value, adjusted_value. The list may hold multiple entries with the same name, and I am having trouble devising an efficient way to condense the list based on the name to where I will a list of similar objects but the values stored will be name, sum(value), sum(adjusted_value).

Is there an efficient way to do this? My current method has for loops inside of a do-while.

Clarfication:

I have a list of obejcts :

```
    {id,date,name,value,ajusted_value},
    {1,"10/30/2014","peaches",4,3}
    {2,"10/30/2014","apples",2,2}
    {3,"10/31/2014","peaches",3,1}
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to condense to list based the name value to one that looks like this:

```
   {null,null,"peaches",7,4}
   {null,null,"apples",2,2}
   .
   .
   .
```

However, I found that HashMap's put() functionality will perform what I desire automatically, but now I need to do this sort of action in Javascript if possible.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm not fully clear on what your question/problem is. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please clarify.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels guess it should be kind of GROUP BY logic

Comment: @StanislavL: thanks, you're probably right (as per usual).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a Map where the key is the `name` and value is the object instance.

Go through the list and for each instance check whether it exists in the map.

If not just add to the map. `map.put(instance.name,instance)`

If it's already added to the map just

```
mapInstance=map.get(instance.name);
mapInstance.value+=instance.value;
mapInstance.adjusted_value+=instance.adjusted_value;
```

After the loop you have the filled map with grouped data

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Guava` in two step. Use a `NameFunction` to convert the list to a `Multimap`. Use a `CondenseFunction` to convert the values of the `Multimap`.

```
  Function<MyClass, String> toName = new Function(){ 
        public String apply(MyClass input){return input.name;}};

  ImmutableListMultimap<String, MyClass> multimap = Multimaps.index(myList, toName);

  Map<String, Collection<MyClass>> map = multimap.asMap();

  Function<Collection<MyClass>, MyClass> condense= new Function(){ 
        public MyClass apply(Collection<MyClass>input){
          // create sums here
  }};

   Map<String, MyClass> condensed = Maps.transformValues(map, condense);
   Collection<MyClass> result = condensed.getValues();
```

[Multimaps.index()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function))

[Maps.transformValues](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function))

Comment: The solution would be much slower than mine. I suggested a way to get sums in one loop. BTW condense function should return MyClass rather than String

Comment: I agree WRT performance. However, I think it is a simpler, less error-prone solution since `Multimap` takes care of checking if the key exists. The code ONLY has to worry about getting the key and combining values. That is, if you are cool with functional programming that the above makes sense. ;) Cheers.